# Ansible Regex (Python) exclude operation

Tags: python, regex, ansible

Ansible uses python regex to search a pattern and replace strings.
DOC link: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html

Below line is one of lines in the file "file.txt".

JAVA_OPT="firststring=value"

I want to concatenate it with the string 'secondstring=value' and avoid concatenation operation if the string is there.

lineinfile: dest="/home/abc/file.txt" regexp='^JAVA_OPT="(.*)"' line='JAVA_OPT="\1 secondstring=value"' backrefs="yes"

I want below string irrespective of multiple runs. Currently, it concatenates the string in every run.
JAVA_OPT="firststring=value secondstring=value"

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Try `regexp='^JAVA_OPT="([^"]*)"(?! secondstring=value)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks for your response. I tried but it didn't help. I am using following expression and it worked:). '^JAVA_OPT="(.*)(?<! secondstring=value)"'

Answer (score 0):

Since [Ansible uses Python regular expressions](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html), you may use

```
regexp='^JAVA_OPT="([^"]*)"(?! secondstring=value)'
```

The `(?! secondstring=value)` negative lookahead will fail the match if  `secondstring=value` is already present after the `JAVA_OPT="..."`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZ8nH8/1)